# I am making an ERP system in Node and PostgreSQL. I want to create task , and no other task should be created in that minute

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, scheduled-tasks

`

```
exports.addTask = ErrorAsyncCatch(async(req, res) => {
    // const task_code = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.task_code, 10);
    const {task_name, task_description, task_code, dept_id} = req.body;
    if(dept_id > 3 || dept_id < 0)
    {
        res.status(400).json({
            success: false,
            message: "No such department exists"
        })
        return
    }
    await client.query("INSERT INTO tasks (task_name, task_description, task_code, dept_id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING *;",
    [task_name, task_description, task_code, dept_id],
    (err, result)=> {
        if(err){
            res.status(err.status).json({
                success: false,
                message: err.message
            })
        }
        else{
            res.status(200).json({
                message: "Data created Successfully",
                data: result.rows[0],
            });
        }    
    }
    );
});
```

`
Can anyone tell me How can I do it?

I am totally new in Node Js I try to use Node-cron but it runs after minutes automatically and dont stop.

Comment: Do you really need to use Node-Cron? Could you just record a "last update time" and when adding to the database, check whether the minute has passed?

Comment: No, I don't have any intent to use Node-Cron. I just want to know how can i try it

Comment: Yes, so when you upload a new task, you can do an if-statement to check whether the most recent task uploaded belongs to the same minute. If it does, then don't upload the new task into the database. That way, you won't be uploading tasks into the database in the same minute. Am I making any sense and have I understood your use case?

Comment: sorry to say, but can you do it in code if you don't mind

Comment: Sorry I am not very familiar with the query language you are using. In pseudo code...`if (latest_update_time + 1 minute < time.now) { //insert task into database } else { // do nothing }` Sorry if I misunderstood your use case